# Sorting second array with respect to first array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting, ecmascript-6

For eg.My

```
Mainarray = [{label:a,value:5} ,
{label :b , value :4 },
{label :c , value :10},
{label :d , value :5}]
```

and my array to be sorted is

```
array1 = [ {label :c ,value 5},{label :a ,value:2}
```

after array1 is sorted it must be like this

```
sortedarray= [{label:a,value :2} ,
{label :b , value :0 },
{label :c , value :5},
{label :d , value :0}]
```

so basically , it must be sorted with respect to MainArray Label , and also if that label doesnt exist in array1, it should append the same label on same index with value 0

Comment: This is not sorting... Or?

Comment: then what do u call it ,, Basically the result must look like sortedarray

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: @BhaveshKale If you call it sorting, then we are looking what kind of sorting you want to achieve. But this has nothing to do with sorting, it seems that you just want to replace value of an array with values from another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could collect the new values in a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and map the data array with new values or zero.

```js
var data = [{ label: 'a', value: 5 }, { label: 'b', value: 4 }, { label: 'c', value: 10 }, { label: 'd', value: 5 }],
    array = [{ label: 'c', value: 5 }, { label: 'a', value: 2 }],
    values = new Map(array.map(({ label, value }) => [label, value])),
    result = data.map(({ label }) => ({ label, value: values.get(label) || 0 }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It is giving an Error Message " Argument of type 'any[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReadonlyArray<[{}, {}]>'.
  Type 'any[]' is missing the following properties from type '[{}, {}]': 0, 1"

Comment: i have no idea of typescript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map to the dataset you want, then sort the mapped dataset.  Here is an example. Hope that helps!

```js
const array = [
  { label: 'c', value: 5 },
  { label: 'b', value: 4 },
  { label: 'a', value: 10 },
  { label: 'd', value: 5 }
]

const toSort = [
  { label: 'b', value: 1 },
  { label: 'a', value: 5 },
  { label: 'c', value: 2 }
];

const mapToSort = array.map(_ => {
  const item = toSort.find(x => x.label === _.label);
  return item || { label: _.label, value: 0 };
})

const getIndex = item => array.findIndex(_ => _.label === item.label);
const sorted = mapToSort.sort((a, b) => getIndex(a) - getIndex(b));

console.log(JSON.stringify(sorted));
```

Comment: It worked , but it is getting sorted Alphabetically

Comment: How else were you going to sort it?  You said you were trying to sort by label.  Not sure what you want here.

Comment: Yes , i want to sort it with respect to label of main array ,, so if main array has label = b,z,c and my second array is c,z,b .. after sorting it must be b,z,c i.e Sorted with respect to Label .. and not alphabet

Comment: It sounds like you want to sort based on the index of the label.  I have updated my answer accordingly.  Hope that helps!